# Get the html (source code) index of a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have

```
<div>
hello
</div>
```

and I select 'hello' with my cursor, the start index is 6, end is 11 (inclusive).

Is there a way to get this information cross-browser with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Probably not. You can do it in `<textareas>`, but not anything else as far as I know. What's this for?

Comment: Would HTML 5's [contenteditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) attribute work, perhaps?

Comment: hmm. that's kinda neat. I'll look inta that.

Comment: With a great deal of effort, you might be able to *guess* the selection based on mouse clicks.

Comment: In response to the question, no. The source HTML is used to create a document object, javascript operates on that object, not on the source HTML which can be considered to no longer exist. For example, browsers are required to remove whitespace after the opening tag and before any non-whitespace characters. Similarly at the end, and all intermediate whitespace is compressed to a single space. The HTML you get from the *innerHTML* and *outerHTML* properties is generated from the DOM, is browser-dependent and is usually missing some or all of the whitespace that was in the source markup.

Comment: This works fine in theory until you consider dynamic page contents (Did that Ad banner just add a new `IFrame` or `Div`?, what happens if some content is loaded during your edit?). You'd be far safer to define the contents of a single element as your editable area (say a div), then use either an editor you write yourself or found on the net.

Comment: @RobG's written what I would have said. Why do you want this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've jQuery included you can do:

`var selectionText = $(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()).text()`

Comment: It's not the actual index of the html as if the html were a string, but it'll be able to accomplish the same task =D